# Is there a way to change the default template for all posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating posts in wordpress programmatically using php. Is there a way to change the post attributes template either programmatically or using the admin panel for all posts? I would like the default to be Product details as you see in the picture below.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/iWMGW1W]

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after creating post programmatically assign page template.

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page-template.php' );
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I will add this line as well to check for errors. if ( $post_id && ! is_wp_error( $post_id ) ){
      
    }